# Azure Batch Insert: Bad Request Error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am getting below error while trying to insert multiple entities in Azure Table storage:

```
com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceException: Bad Request
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableBatchOperation$1.postProcessResponse(TableBatchOperation.java:525)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableBatchOperation$1.postProcessResponse(TableBatchOperation.java:433)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:146)
```

Below is the Java code for batch insert:

```
public BatchInsertResponse batchInsert(BatchInsertRequest request){
    BatchInsertResponse response = new BatchInsertResponse();

    String erpName = request.getErpName();
    HashMap<String,List<TableEntity>> tableNameToEntityMap = request.getTableNameToEntityMap();

     HashMap<String,List<TableEntity>> errorMap = new HashMap<String,List<TableEntity>>();
     HashMap<String,List<TableEntity>> successMap =  new HashMap<String,List<TableEntity>>();;

     CloudTable cloudTable=null;

     for (Map.Entry<String, List<TableEntity>> entry : tableNameToEntityMap.entrySet()){
         try {
                cloudTable = azureStorage.getTable(entry.getKey());                 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

      // Define a batch operation.
            TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
            List<TableEntity> value = entry.getValue();

            for (int i = 0; i < value.size(); i++) {
                TableEntity entity = value.get(i) ;
                batchOperation.insertOrReplace(entity);
                if (i!=0 && i % batchSize == 0) {
                    try {
                        cloudTable.execute(batchOperation);
                        batchOperation.clear();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }
            }


                try {
                    cloudTable.execute(batchOperation);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
     }  

}
```

Above code is working fine if I will assign batchSize value to 10 but if I will assign to 1000 or 100 it will throw Bad request error.

Please help me to resolve this error. I am using Spring boot and Azure-storage Java SDK version 4.3.0.

Comment: Generally 400 Error means there's something wrong with the value of one of your properties. One way to find out is to trace the request/response through Fiddler and see the actual data being sent. It is possible there are some datatype mismatch.

Comment: e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusMessage will provide you the exact reason for the failure

Comment: @Aravind I think data is correct because I am able to insert same data by setting batchSize =10.

Comment: Thanks @Aravind. You were right this is a data problem. I am getting this error when I am trying to insert duplicate entity in a single batch operation (insert/update). Therefore I removed duplicate entities and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Aravind mentioned, 400 error usually means there's something wrong with your data. From [`this`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894038.aspx) link, an entity batch transaction will fail if one or more of the following conditions are not met:

- All entities subject to operations as part of the transaction **must have the same PartitionKey value**.
- **An entity can appear only once in the transaction**, and only one operation may be performed against it.
- The transaction can include **at most 100 entities**, and its **total payload may be no more than 4 MB in size**.
- All entities are subject to the limitations described in [Understanding the Table Service Data Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx).

Please check your entities against these four rules and ensure that you're not violating one of the rules.

Comment: For this batch operation I am using  total 5 Azure tables with at least 4000 rows. Hence data payload is more than 4MB. Is there any way that I can use payload  more than 4MB and more than 100 entities for a single transaction?

Comment: No you can't. These are the hard limits and you can't override them. You would need to split the entity batch into smaller batches so that you don't violate the rules mentioned above and try those batches separately. HTH.

Comment: Is there any way that I can find batch data payload size? So i will be able to make sure that for every batch request payload size must be < 4MB.

Comment: Please see this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2011/11/30/how-the-size-of-an-entity-is-caclulated-in-windows-azure-table-storage/ to calculate size of an entity in a batch. Add some extra bytes for other things included in the payload. HTH.